# Not able to register user after UserStorageProvider config in Keycloak

Tags: keycloak

In Keycloak, when I try to add user to Keycloak local storage after configuring external storage in User Federation section, I get "User exists with same username" error.

Here is what I did.

1. I created a new realm and client.  Then, I was able to add an user of my choice without issue into Keycloak local storage
2. I configured an external UserStorageProvider at User Federation section.  Then, I was not able to add user into Keycloak local storage nor able to create an user using self-registration mode.

Can you please help?

Comment: You should provide more details about the configuration, errors you get, sample code, etc. so that people could help you.

Comment: which federation provider are you using ? most probably users are sync in the Keycloak DB. that's why you cannot create new user with same username

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an expected behavior and not an issue. Keycloak expects you have a unique user hence it throws you an duplicate user exception.

You could delete the user which you have created in the first run, and let your user spi manage the process.

Or
First create your normal keycloak users, then add a User federation to manage different set of users, that way you address both requirements.

As a hack, you could still have same user in both keycloak local and User SPI, for this

1. Create a Realm(R1) and a client.
2. Create a user(U1) in the realm.
3. Create user(U1) in your federation database.
4. Link the User SPI in your realm(R1).

Now you have two duplicate users(U1) in your realm. **This is not recommended for obvious complexities**.